# Move sidebars to the left side

Tags: magento2, layout, sidebar

I want to move the sidebars you can see on the image to the left side.

How can I do that?

I have absolutely no idea about Magento Layouts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change in Catalog -> Categories -> {Select the category}

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need changes category page layout from `2columns right` to   2`columns left`.

open **`catalog_category_view.xml`** from `app/design/{ThemeVendor}/{Themename}/Magento_Catalog/layout`  changes

`layout="2columns-right"`to `layout="2columns-right"`

**Note that need to flush cache**

if it is not work then checked, admin

the category layout, go to Products -> Categories -> Select your desired Category  go to the Design tab and  check forcefully it set from admin

Comment: I can't find layout="2columns-right" in catalog_category_view. Can you post the modified file? Thanks!

Comment: You may  have `<pagexmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">` then just changes `<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">`